# Ionic@beta Installation –verbose output shows ok. but ionic@beta not installed yet

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic2

My Version Details are as follows:

> **npm     : 3.9.0 cordova : 5.3.3 nodejs  : v5.11.0**

When I give the command for installing the ionic@beta
`npm i -g --verbose ionic@beta`

I get the following reply in the cmd:

```
C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST>npm i -g --verbose ionic@beta
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli
C:\\Users\\thinkdigitalGST\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'i',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'ionic@beta' ]
npm info using npm@3.9.0
npm info using node@v5.11.0
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 2:29:43 PM
npm verb request id 5ce45225f4456541
npm verb etag "B3KI53MOJ2OGQ3XZPTDE0Z1A5"
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm verb headers { date: 'Mon, 16 May 2016 08:59:48 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"B3KI53MOJ2OGQ3XZPTDE0Z1A5"',
npm verb headers   age: '224',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-ams4138-AMS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1463389188.994969,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic from cache
npm verb get saving ionic to C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb cache add spec ionic@beta
npm verb addNamed "beta" is being treated as a dist-tag for ionic
npm info addNameTag [ 'ionic', 'beta' ]
npm verb addNameTag registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic not in flight; fetching
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 2:30:21 PM
npm verb etag "B3KI53MOJ2OGQ3XZPTDE0Z1A5"
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm verb headers { date: 'Mon, 16 May 2016 09:00:25 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: '"B3KI53MOJ2OGQ3XZPTDE0Z1A5"',
npm verb headers   age: '260',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-ams4138-AMS',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '2',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1463389225.102092,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic from cache
npm verb get saving ionic to C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb addNamed "2.0.0-beta.25" is a plain semver version for ionic
npm verb addRemoteTarball https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.0.0-beta.25.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.0.0-beta.25.tgz',
npm verb addRemoteTarball   '0184b9f610b8c52e72bfa287eebcdde08a1443be' ]
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 2:30:22 PM
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 2:30:22 PM
npm http fetch GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.0.0-beta.25.tgz
npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.0.0-beta.25.tgz
npm verb addTmpTarball C:\Users\THINKD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5468-a502604a\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\-\ionic-2.0.0-beta.25.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addTmpTarball already have metadata; skipping unpack for ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ionic\2.0.0-beta.25\package\package.json not in flight; writing
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb afterAdd C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ionic\2.0.0-beta.25\package\package.json written
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb addBundled extract C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ionic\2.0.0-beta.25\package.tgz
npm verb tar unpack C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ionic\2.0.0-beta.25\package.tgz
npm verb tar unpacking to C:\Users\THINKD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5468-a502604a\unpack-9ea5ad4f
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\THINKD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5468-a502604a\unpack-9ea5ad4f
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb makeDirectory C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks creation not in flight; initializing
npm verb makeCacheDir UID & GID are irrelevant on win32
npm verb lock using C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-356c471ddde029cf.lock for C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm\node_modules\.staging
npm verb unbuild node_modules\.staging\ionic-dd1cc71b
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm\node_modules\.staging\ionic-dd1cc71b
npm verb tar unpack C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ionic\2.0.0-beta.25\package.tgz
npm verb tar unpacking to C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm\node_modules\.staging\ionic-dd1cc71b
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm\node_modules\.staging\ionic-dd1cc71b
npm verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm\node_modules\.staging\ionic-dd1cc71b\node_modules
npm info lifecycle ionic@2.0.0-beta.25~preinstall: ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
npm info linkStuff ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
npm verb linkBins ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
npm verb link bins [ { ionic: 'bin/ionic' },
npm verb link bins   'C:\\Users\\thinkdigitalGST\\npm',
npm verb link bins   true ]
npm verb linkMans ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
npm info lifecycle ionic@2.0.0-beta.25~install: ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
npm info lifecycle ionic@2.0.0-beta.25~postinstall: ionic@2.0.0-beta.25
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-356c471ddde029cf.lock for C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm\node_modules\.staging
C:\Users\thinkdigitalGST\npm
    ``-- ionic@2.0.0-beta.25`

    npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
    npm info ok
```

Does it mean that I have installed Ionic@beta???

Once I give the following command:

```
ionic -v
```

It shows me the following:

```
'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Ionic is not installed in your system.

Try the command `npm install -g ionic`

Also check you have installed all the required environment set up.

Install Node js once again or start the installation process from beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) 

The main thing is, I need Ionic 2 and also the Node JS is up to date and I have installed it for 4 times and have all my environment variables set up. I have checked them more than a dozen times. Still the same problem :/

Comment: I tried to install ionic now as you said! It fills the command line so fast and I can't even read it finally it stops at a place where I get the directory names! I'm still blank. May be there is somthing wrong with my system :/

Comment: I got ionic 2 installed in my system. But whenever I try to start a new  ionic 2 project it's downloading normal project. Seems like error on getting template.